Domain Driven Design Application Layer in an ASP.NET application
I am developing an ASP.NET application using domain-driven design.
It will be used by a React web site as the front end.
In the canonical DDD approach, should the ASP.NET project serve as our application layer, or should I add another, separate project to be application layer for the project?
For now I am using ASP.NET project as an application layer, but I am not sure.
I understand that the React web site will be the presentation layer.
Thank you :)

Depends on a few factors- first and foremost agreement between those who will write/maintain the codebase, then how big will the project is expected to be and how frequently changed. You shouldn't blindly follow a paradigm without knowing why it will benefit you and evaluating the risks of using it.
If you go by the book an ASP.NET project sound more like your presentation layer than the application one (web frameworks are probably not in your domain language :) ). But still it's hard to say without knowing your full requirements and the way the codebase will be generally used.

React app is separate application. I would look at presentation layer as how you expose your application, which is backend application. And you expose your app through API. If you would use Razor project, it would be just another presentation layer, etc.

Great, thank you very much.
I do not want to follow the paradigm just for paradigm's sake, I truly want to understand :)
Really appreciate your comments!

In my opinion, you could use a separate asp.net core web api as the application layer and the react as the presentation layer is OK. Since if you are using the react, inside the server side using a web api is a good choice to provide the rest api for the react.
But for design the whole project, you need firstly consider what's the requirement(business) you want to manage, since the DDD advocates modeling based on the reality of business as relevant to your use cases. In the context of building applications, DDD talks about problems as domains.
Then according to these domains(businuess requirement)' decide which technology you want to use.

If you want to truly separate the infrastructure of the web framework(actually all concerns related to web communication between clients/servers) from the use cases, than you should have a separate Application Layer. Your Application Code(Layer) is specific to your ASP.NET API application and is used only by it, the Presentation Layer(your ASP.NET API) on the other hand could be used by multiple Front-end or Back-end applications(Clients). Whether you place it in separate project or folder is up to you.
The only advantage of having your Application Logic in the API Methods/Controllers is simplicity and reduced time of development, which should be decided on project to project basis as time is a crucial part in the whole picture of delivering software.

For an ASP.NET Web API paired with a React application, which I think is what you're doing, I would usually opt to have the application logic in separate projects.
But as per the comments on your question, the answer really is "it depends." So to help you make your own choice here are some of the reasons I do it. You can decide which of them are important to you.
Practical benefits

Unit Testing is trivial. You don't have to worry about ASP.NET controllers and all the infrastructure they need. You can just instantiate your application logic, mock the dependencies, and test them.

Isolation from ASP.NET versions. There are inevitably changes to ASP.NET throughout the life of your application. The more you can de-couple the application logic from ASP.NET, the more likely these upgrades will go smoothly.


Structural benefits

Clearer separation of responsibilities in the application.

ASP.NET: Authentication, authorisation, dependency injection, and all the other non-functional aspects.
Application layer: Business logic.


Enables breaking up a project between different development teams. For example, parts of the application logic could be developed and published as Nuget packages for your ASP.NET Web API developers to consume.


An illustrative code example
ASP.NET Web API controller
This handles the HTTP requests and ensures they're correctly authorised. It has no business logic at all.
namespace MyApp.Endpoints;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Roles = "Owner,Manager")] // Roles for the entire controller
public class SomeEndpointController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly WidgetService _service;

    public SomeEndpointController(WidgetService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Owner")] // Roles overridden for this method
    public async Widget GetAvailableWidgetsAsync(string type)
    {
        // No business logic. It just calls into your application layer.
        return await _service.GetAvailableWidgetsAsync(type);
    }

    #region Other methods
    #endregion
}

Application layer
This has the methods that a presentation layer (i.e. your React application) would find useful.
namespace MyApp.Application;

public class WidgetService(
    IWidgetInfoRepository _widgetInfo,
    IWidgetInventoryRepository _widgetInventory)
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Widget>> GetAvailableWidgetsAsync(string type)
    {
        if (type == String.Empty) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); // Validation

        // Some fictional business logic.
        var widgets = await _widgetInfo.GetAll(type);
        var inventory = await _widgetInventory.GetFor(widgets);

        return widgets.Where(w => w.HasEnough(inventory)).ToArray();
    }
}

Domain layer
This might be just part of your application layer project, or it might be separate.
namespace MyApp.Application.Domain;

public class Widget
{
    #region Properties
    #endregion

    public bool HasEnough(IEnumerable<InventoryRecord> inventory)
    {
        // Some business rules...
    }
}

Note for the domain layer, you might choose between either:

Having it as part of your application layer project. Or;
Separate it out into another project, particularly if it might be re-used by several different applications.

You might opt for the second option if you have multiple applications. Perhaps, in addition to the React app, you have an integration receiving data from connected systems. You can imagine they'd have very different application layers, but would want to share the same domain entities and business rules.
Unit tests
You can use unit tests for automated testing of your business logic, without having to consider ASP.NET at all.
namespace MyApp.UnitTests;

public class WidgetTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestWidgetAvailability()
    {
        var mockWidgets = Helpers.CreateSomeWidgets();
        var mockInventory = Helpers.CreateEmptyInventory();

        var service = new WidgetService(mockWidgets, mockInventory);
        var freeWidgets = await service.GetAvailableWidgetsAsync();

        Assert.Equal(0, freeWidgets.Count());
    }
}

Summary
Feel free to make your own choice, based on how complex your application is likely to be. It depends how much of the above you are concerned about. There is no single "best" approach!

Great! Thank you very much, especially for putting an actual example.
This helps me a lot :)

No problem! Please upvote it if you think it's useful so that others can find it too!
